# Loading ViewControllers within Storyboard

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboard

I am using a side view controller setup using this : https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController

The initial View Controller is loaded using the storyboard with an identifier of 'InitialViewController'.

Once loaded in the viewDidLoad for this, I check if the user is logged in using the below:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard;

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
} else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];
}

if (![PFUser currentUser]){
    self.topViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WelcomeVC"];
} else {
    self.topViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeVC"];
}
```

Per the above, if the user is not logged in it loads the WelcomeVC.
The WelcomeVC is a Navigation Controller that has 3 Vc's within it. Welcome/Login/Signup.

Once the user logs in I need to change the topViewController (like above) to be the HomeVC. The navigation controller known as WelcomeVC can be dismissed, if possible.
How do I change this topViewController I have tried this but it does not work:

UIStoryboard *storyboard;

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
} else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];
}

self.EVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InitialViewController"];
self.EVC.topViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeVC"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I like to make the home screen to be the root view controller from the start, and have `viewDidAppear` automatically take me to the login screen via a non-animated modal segue (I prefer `performSegueWithIdentifier` so that the storyboard's segues show the whole flow, rather than manually instantiating the controller and calling `pushViewController`, but whatever works for you). I then, upon successful login, simply dismiss back to the main screen. That way, I don't have to play around with changing the top level controller.

So my storyboard looks like:

[image]

So my main "home" view controller has the following `viewDidAppear`:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    if (![[Model sharedManager] loggedIn])
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self];
}
```

Clearly, your logic for determining whether you're logged in will vary, but you get the idea. My login does a modal segue (sans animation) to the login screen and I happen to be using a navigation controller on the series of login screens.

My final, successful login process then does:

```
- (IBAction)didTouchUpInsideDoneButton:(id)sender
{
    // ok, assuming at this point that everything has been validated and 
    // I'm ready to return, so just dismiss the navigation controller.
    // You could use unwind segue in iOS 6, as well.

    [[Model sharedManager] setLoggedIn:YES];

    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Great answer, before I try and implement. Can you confirm they I can model show a navigation controller for the login? I thought I could only modal one controller. If this is the case I have three controllers that I use for the login so I would need to modal each one and dismiss as required.

Comment: @StuartM - Yes, you can do modal segue from home to navigation controller, push segue from welcome to login to sign-up and "dismiss" back to home screen. The above storyboard and code is from working demonstration.

Comment: Thanks @Rob I figured it out from your answer which is great. I was actually able to include my initialviewcontroller class and simply access self.slidingviewcontroller.topviewcontroller then instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier as normal. Do you know if this handles releasing the older views from the storyboard as no longer needed?

Comment: @StuartM - Using my technique, where rather than mucking with the top controller, but start at the real "home" screen, modal to the welcome/login/sign up series, and dismiss back, yes they're released properly. I confirmed this by putting in a `dealloc` on each controller that just does `NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);`. You should do the same and confirm that they're getting released for you.

Comment: It looks like my controller is being dealloc through my route as well which is great, thanks for the time on the dealloc method, very useful.

Answer (score 0):

In application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, I check to see if a user is logged in already, and if they are, I jump to the profile:

```
-(void)goToProfile {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.window.rootViewController.storyboard;
    UINavigationController *rootNav = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainNavigationController"];
    if (![self.window.rootViewController isKindOfClass:[rootNav class]]) {
        self.window.rootViewController = rootNav;
    }
    else {
        [(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

The didFinishLaunchingWithOptions doesn't need anything else in it.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([self isLoggedIn]) {
        [self goToProfile];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Not logged in");
    }
    return YES;    
}
```

In my storyboard, the primary branch goes to a signup process, and the navigation controller of the logged in view has a storyboard ID of MainNavigationController.
[image: my storyboard]